# Использование readline() в библиотеке pyserial

Tags: python, readline, pyserial

Подскажите как использовать `readline()` для приёма данных по uart интерфейсу. Насколько я понял из документации `readline()` принимает все последовательные данные с ком порта пока не придёт EOL - `\n`. Собственно вопрос что такое `\n`? Это буква n в unicode? То есть у меня будут читаться и будут возвращены все данные, когда по последовательному интерфейсу не придёт последовательность бит `01101110`? Данные я посылаю с ПЛИС. И не могу понять что мне нужно сформировать чтобы пакет правильно принимался.

Comment: Это условное обозначение символа переноса строки

Comment: В битах это 00001010

Comment: А в байткоде это записывается `b'\n'`? И если я сформирую `00001010` со стороны ПЛИС то на компе это будет расцениваться как EOL, и будт возвращены все данные которые были приняты до этого?

Answer (score 0):

Мб кто-нибудь наткнётся через Гугл на эту тему. Поэтому напишу результаты моих изысканий. Проверил с ПЛИС. Для того чтобы `readline()` работал адекватно. В конце каждой посылки нужно формировать следующую последовательность бит - `00001010`. Пайтоном это воспринимается как `b'\n'`. Но принятые данные печатаются с `\n` в конце. Например - `b'\xea\x8f\x1f\n'`. Для того чтобы избавиться от `\n` в конце использовал следующее:

```
def read_com_port(port_name, baud_rate):
ser = serial.Serial(port_name, bauderate=baude_rate)
    while True:
        buf = ser.readline()
        if len(buf) != 4:
            continue
        in = (int.from_bytes(buf, byteorder="big") - 0xa) / 256
```

`byteorder` зависит от того какой байт вы посылаете первый. У меня первое восьмибитное слово данных - это старшие разряды кода угла. Поэтому указанно `big`. Если у вас первым посылается младший байт то указывайте `little`. `- 0xa` это отнимается то самое `\n`. `0xa = 0b1010`. И деление на 256 нужно для того чтобы избавиться от нулей на конце , сдвигом числа вправо 8 раз (2**8), которые получились в результате формирования на ПЛИС `00001010` и вычитания `0xa`.
Upd. Добавил в код проверку длинны посылки.

Comment: Чтобы убрать байт "\n" в конце последовательности байт, достаточно использовать метод rstrip: `buf = ser.readline().rstrip(b"\n")`. Но это правда обрежет все 0xA байты, если их несколько в конце. Если такой байт всегда там есть, то можно просто всегда обрезать последний байт: `buf = ser.readline()[:-1]`

Comment: P.S. если используете Python 3.9 и выше, можно использовать метод removesuffix, он обрежет только один последний "\n": `buf = ser.readline().removesuffix(b"\n")`

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.

Comment: Еще момент: readline предполагает прием строки текста, а не бинарных данных. Если у вас в данных встретится байт с кодом 0x0A, то прием пакета прервется на этом байте. По идее должна быть возможность принимать блоки фиксированного размера, по аналогии с чтением из файла это может быть read: `ser.read(4)` (вместо 4 укажите нужное количество принимаемых байт). Ну и на передающей стороне соответственно нужно тоже передавать без символа переноса, условно, не `writeln` (запись строки с символом переноса в конце, фактически может называться по-другому), а `write`

Comment: Я так пробывал. Это зависит от того в какой момент времени начался прием данных. Я могу началом приема попасть в середину между вторым и третьим байтами. И тогда у меня будут склеиваться конец одной посылки с началом другой. Я так пробовал. Мб что-то делал не так. В итоге решил разобраться с `readline`.  И использую его. При использовании `readline` учитываю условие что `len(buf) == 4` и если не 4 в цикле прогоняю заново чтение порта.

Comment: На передающей стороне все формируется на низком уровне, исключительно 0 и 1. Я так понимаю вы имеете ввиду Ардуино и микроконтроллеры. Я с ними сталкивался но давно, и не плотно. При программировании ПЛИС используется язык verilog HDL. На нем описывается цифровая микросхема, которая в соответствии с кодом синтезируется на ПЛИС. Поэтому у меня и возник вопрос что на уровне бит сформировать чтобы завершить прием с помощью `readline` .

Comment: 0 и 1 формируют байты, и есть ненулевая вероятность того, что получится последовательность бит 0000 1010 (0xA), это доставит вам проблемы, если вы будете использовать readline. Вообще не важно что на передающей стороне. Главное придумать "протокол", который позволит однозначно декодировать приходящие байты.

Comment: В таком случае эта посылка у меня на пройдёт по длине, и я пропущу эти 4 байта. Частота работы uart высокая, и потеря одной посылки не сказывается на точности. Для моих нужд этого достаточно. Если посылается какой-то текст, например, с Ардуино, где нельзя пропускать байты, да, это может быть проблемой.